# Cannot turn Elasticsearch dynamic mapping on

Tags: elasticsearch, dynamic, field, logstash, mappings

I disabled dynamic mapping with

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_template/template_all?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {  "template": "*",  "order":0,  "settings": {    "index.mapper.dynamic": false   }}'
```

I wanted to turn it back on with

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_template/template_all?pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' {  "template": "*",  "order":0,  "settings": {    "index.mapper.dynamic": true   }}'
```

It has confirmed it as true, but when I try to have logstash send information to it, in logstash error logs I get back-

```
"reason"=>"trying to auto create mapping, but dynamic mapping is disabled"
```

How do I actually turn dynamic mapping back on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like index for logstash was created with old template (before you update template). Because when you update you template only new indexes will have updated mapping and settings.

Check is index exists:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/LOGSTASH_INDEX_NAME_HERE'
```

If index exists and you can delete this index - do it. After this when logstash will try to send something - index will be created with the new mapping.